# How to insert data in the firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

So i have problem regarding adding the appointment details in my firebase android studio. I want the user to store their appointment details in appointment database and I also want to check if the user has booked the date and day. However , after the user has pressed the  confirm button, it doesnt store the appointment details in the firebase and it also doesnt prompt the dialog message to the user indicating that their appointment has been registered successfully? Is there any way to solve this problem ? The code is shown as below :

```
private void addAppointment() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("idPatient", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        hashMap.put("idDoctor", idDoctor);
        hashMap.put("time", time.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("date", day.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("status", "On hold");


    DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Appointment");
    reference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Appointment relationship = data.getValue(Appointment.class);
                if (relationship.getTime().equals(time.getText().toString()) && relationship.getDate().equals(day.getText().toString()) && relationship.getIdDoctor().equals(idDoctor)) {
                    new SweetAlertDialog(BookAppointmentActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("Oops...")
                            .setContentText("The date and time has been booked")
                            .show();

                }else if(snapshot.exists()){
                    reference.child("Appointment").push().setValue(hashMap);
                    new SweetAlertDialog(BookAppointmentActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("Congratulations")
                            .setContentText("Your appointment is registered successfully")
                            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(BookAppointmentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You can check the official documentation, that will most likely be helpful : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: There is a lot that could be going wrong here, so I recommend setting breakpoints on each important line, running the code in the debugger, and checking whether all variables on that line have the value you expect. If not, which is the first line that doesn't, and what value is different from what you expected? --- Also: don't ignore errors. At its minimum, `onCancelled` should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the firebase rules, read and write are set to true as per your requirements
[image]

Answer (score 0):

so first of all you can create a modal class for all the children (example - doctor, time, status )

```java
package com.example.chatapp;

public class UserModel {

    String name;
    String phone;
    String about;
    String url;



    String uid;

    public UserModel(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }


}
```

then declare this modal class

```java
Usermodal modal = new Modal class
```

then insert data like

```java
modal.setname(yourdata);
```

then write

```java
databaseref.child(key).setvalue(modal);
```

you can refer to [this link](https://youtu.be/td1jX_zDi5s) for more.